# How to copy records which do not exist in the target table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I create a temporary table which I fill with external data.

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp AS SELECT * FROM saireco.employee LIMIT 0;
```

Next, I want to copy all records which exist in the temporary table to the target table.

```sql
INSERT INTO saireco.employee
SELECT *
FROM tmp t
LEFT JOIN saireco.employee e USING ("employeeID")
WHERE e."employeeID" IS NULL;
```

The results in an error

ERROR:  INSERT has more expressions than target columns
LINE 2: SELECT *

The reason is that SELECT * not only results the columns from the temporary table, but also the columns from the target table resulting in more columns than the target table contains.

How can I only return the columns from the temporary table?

Comment: Try select t.* or add the column names of t.

Answer (score 0):

Your join combined with `select *` returns all columns of **both** tables, not only those from the `tmp` table.

One way to solve it, is to explicitly specify the target columns and those in the source:

```
insert into saireco.employee (col1, col2, col2)
select t.col1, t.col2, t.col3
from tmp t
  LEFT JOIN saireco.employee e USING ("employeeID")
WHERE e."employeeID" IS NULL;
```

Or as both tables have the same structure (including the order of the columns), you can use `select t.*` to only get the columns of the tmp table:

```
insert into saireco.employee 
select t.*
from tmp t
  LEFT JOIN saireco.employee e USING ("employeeID")
WHERE e."employeeID" IS NULL;
```

Alternatively you can use a `NOT EXISTS` that doesn't increase the number of columns in the output:

```
insert into saireco.employee 
select *
from tmp t
where not exists (select * 
                  from saireco.employee e 
                  where employeeID" t."employeeID");
```

But specifying the target columns **and** and specifying the output columns is good coding practice and should also be done in the second solution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  Does specifying the target columns and output columns impact performance?

Comment: No, there is no negative impact on performance

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should use t.* to return the columns of the table t

```
INSERT INTO saireco.employee
SELECT t.*
FROM tmp t
LEFT JOIN saireco.employee e USING ("employeeID")
WHERE e."employeeID" IS NULL;
```

But if the primary key column in the employee table is IDENTITY , you must specify the column names explicitly because the IDENTITY  column will not accept the insert , and the code will be better clear
Exp:

```
 INSERT INTO saireco.employee
 ( employeeName ,  phone , .....)
 SELECT t.employeeName, employee.phone ....
 FROM tmp t
 LEFT JOIN saireco.employee e USING ("employeeID")
 WHERE e."employeeID" IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. For now I have gone with WHERE NOT EXISTS.